# Recharts - Tooltip Formatter on Biaxial Line Charts?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I'm using a Biaxial Line Chart, and I'm trying to figure out how to format the content of the Tooltip using the formatter function.

What I want is for my output to read:

```
2019-01-13
Price: $17.99
Sales Rank: 326,518
```

I'm currently using the below code which formats the price into a price, but it does not change the sales rank value.  I'm also not sure on how to change the labels?

```
<Tooltip formatter={(value, name) => (name === "price") ? `$${value/100}` : value.toLocaleString()}/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to format the label in particular, you can use `labelFormatter` instead of `formatter`:

```
<Tooltip
  labelFormatter={value => {
    return `label: ${value}`;
  }} 
/>
```

Comment: this would change the date in his case, wouldn't it? Not the price & sales_rank

Comment: @trainoasis yes, in case everything needs formatting I would use a Custom Tooltip. In case it just the label (in this question - date), labelFormatter works just fine

Answer (score 1):

You can create CustomTooltip Component that can display the data as per your requirement as done below

```
  const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label }) => {
    console.log("payload",payload);  //you check payload
    if (active) {
      return (
        <div>
         <Card>
          <p>{date} </p>
          <p>Price : ${}</p>
          <p>Sales Rank :${} </p>
          <Card>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return null;
  };
```

[payload array image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXJnn.png)
payload variable contain all axis values and data as per your requirement for example

where payload[0] contain x-axis and payload[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXJnn.png) contain  y-axis and payload[2] contain z-axis as per your requirement you can extract value from array

```
       <div>
          <p>{date} </p>
          <p>Price : ${payload[0].data}</p>
          <p>Sales Rank :${payload[1].data} </p>
        </div>
```

and date can we extract from the payload[0].payload which contains entire object of the data that you pass in chart and you can pass your CustomTooltip in Tooltip as below shown

```
<Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip />} />
```

Whenever you cursor over points on graph can able to see the tooltips as you wish

Answer (score 0):

As soon as formatter accepts also props, you can try to alter that object. Props has all the data displayed in a tooltip.

```js
const formatter = (value, name, props) => {
    console.log("V", value, "N", name, "P", props); // for debug
    props.payload = Object.keys(props.payload).map(k => {
        return props.payload[k] = isNaN(props.payload[k]) ? props.payload[k] : format(props.payload[k]);
    })
    return [value, name, props]
}
```

Though I'm **not sure this is a good solution**, because for me it sometimes breaks chart on resize. But maybe you can make it work.